# Left join & ambiguous error

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with a (most likely) very simple problem. I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: ambiguous column name: Rek.name
```

Okay, I theoretically know what this error means means. However, I don't quite get why it appears when I try to use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Rek.name AS abc, COUNT(DISTINCT Fav.FavId) AS def
FROM Rek, Fav
LEFT JOIN Artist ON Rek.RekId = Fav.RekId;
```

Why is Rek.name ambiguous? How can one make it non-ambiguous?

Comment: Can you post your table structures

Comment: Don't mix comma separated implicit joins with explicit joins... (Actually, always do explicit `JOIN`.) Explicit join chains are evaluated before comma separated implicit joins. So the Rek table isn't in scope for the LEFT JOIN's ON clause.

Comment: Are you sure this is the query which generates the actual error?  I don't think it should give this error.  Also, you are doing a cross join to the `Artist` table; probably not what you want. to be doing.

Comment: Don't forget the GROUP BY.

Comment: What database are you using?  Your query, as written, doesn't have an ambiguous reference to `Rek.name`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join Fav table :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Rek.name AS abc, COUNT(DISTINCT Fav.FavId) AS def
FROM Rek
LEFT JOIN Fav ON Rek.RekId = Fav.RekId
GROUP BY Rek.name;
```

If you want also Artist table :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Rek.name AS abc, COUNT(DISTINCT Fav.FavId) AS def
FROM Rek
LEFT JOIN Fav ON Rek.RekId = Fav.RekId
LEFT JOIN Artist ON Rek.common_attribute= Artist.common_attribute
GROUP BY Rek.name;
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems the solution was simple; removing the "Fav" from line 2.I guess I have to study this some more to understand the left join properly.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: I don't no if the group by return no duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Huh?  I think the query you want looks like this:

```
SELECT Rek.name AS abc, COUNT(Fav.RekId) AS def
FROM Rek LEFT JOIN
     Fav
     ON Rek.RekId = Fav.RekId
GROUP BY Rek.name;
```

Notes:

- The `Artist` table is not needed.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is an awkward way of doing `GROUP BY`.
- Presumably `fav.favid` is a primary key.  You don't need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in that case.